# Adding object to array and getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I have a class ConvexHull which I have to implement for my class. One of the instance variables is an array that holds the object Points.

```
private Points[] points;
```

When I go to add a Point to the array in the constructor, I'm given a NullPointerException.

```
public ConvexHull(int n) throws IllegalArgumentException 
{
    if (n < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    else {

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            int x = rand.nextInt(101)-50;
            int y = rand.nextInt(101)-50;
            Point p = new Point(x,y);
            this.points[i] = p;      // NullPointerException is thrown.
            this.numPoints = points.length;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I have no idea why this isn't working and need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please allocate memory for

```
private Points[] points;
```

like this..

```
public ConvexHull(int n) throws IllegalArgumentException 
{

    if (n < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    else {
        points=new Points[n];  //this is the line that is added

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            int x = rand.nextInt(101)-50;
            int y = rand.nextInt(101)-50;
            Point p = new Point(x,y);
            this.points[i] = p;      // NullPointerException is thrown.
            this.numPoints = points.length;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't instantiate the array `points`. You need something like

```
private Point[] points = new Point[i];
```

where i is an integer specifying the array's length. Otherwise `points` is `null` and a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

By the way I don't think there is a class called `Points`. If you create your own class (in fact you probably don't have to),  don't name it using a plural noun.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the problem with your code is that you have declared the array but you have not initialized the array like

```
points = new Point[sizeOfYourArray];
```

and it should fix your problem because there is nothing to start with in the first place so when you initialize it it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't new an object for field "pointer" like `pointer p = new pointer();`, so you will get a NullPointerException.